# Why won't it go to the page I assign to the link

Tags: php

Hello I have trouble passing a value to a link to get to a page where the alias as it's called in this example goes to an unique page for that username. The variable $från_användare works fine in the headers and it won't go to http://localhost/hemsida/
nytt/sendmsg.php?un=$från_användare even if $från_användare = 1;

this is my code

```
<?php
    include("./inc/head.inc.php");
    if(isset($_GET['alias']) && !empty($_GET['alias'])){
        $alias = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['alias']);
        $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM meddelande WHERE från_användare='$$alias'");
        $rader = $sql->num_rows;
        if($rader > 0) {
        }   
    }
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT från_användare, meddelande FROM meddelande WHERE till_användare='$inloggad' GROUP BY från_användare ORDER BY id DESC");

?>
<div id="inutiWrapper">
<h2>Messages</h2>
<div id="vänsterspalt">
<?php
    if($inloggad){
        while($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
        $från_användare = $row['från_användare'];
        $msg = $row['meddelande'];
        echo "<div class='ettmsg'><span><strong>".$från_användare."</strong></span><p>".$msg."</p><a href='sendmsg.php?alias='".$från_användare."'>".$från_användare."</a></div>";
                }
        }
    else{
        echo "<div id='err'>Du måste vara inloggad för att se och kunna skicka meddelanden</div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: View the source and make sure the HTML is what you are expecting. If so, post it in your question.

Comment: Everything is I expect it except it not picking up the exact link. It goes to the right page but without th value "alias" or "un"

Comment: `real_escape_string` does not prevent your SQL being abused and your data trashed. Use `$_GET` variables with extreme caution and run them through a `preg_replace` function or similar before having them anywhere near your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a error in your `ahref` you need to do it like this.

`<a href='sendmsg.php?alias=".$från_användare."'>".$från_användare."</a>`

now it will redirect to your user.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code. First, double dollar sign in your first query. It should be

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM meddelande WHERE från_användare='/* you added $ here */$alias'");
```

Then your second error is in the `href` attribute to your anchor element. This is the error

```
<a href='sendmsg.php?alias='/* this is where your link stopped because y have closed it with the single quote mark which you used to open the link.*/".$från_användare."'>".$från_användare."</a>
```

Instead that should be

```
<a href='sendmsg.php?alias=".$från_användare."'>".$från_användare."</a>
```

Comment: double dollar might be intended; to use a value whose reference is passed by `$_GET`, .... yeah, I think that's extremely unlikely too. But may be worth noting that double dollar sign itself is not a syntax error.